# Set slider plugin as theme's header in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

First, I would like to start by giving the link to our website:

[www.mark-bumgarner.com](https://mark-bumgarner.com/)

Now I will try to break down my dilemma.

1. I am using the theme "[Thebe](https://themeforest.net/item/thebe-portfolio-wordpress-theme/21611115)" to style our website. The theme comes with a built-in slider, which, unfortunately, CANNOT be used in the Header section or as a Hero Slider.
2. A few months ago, the theme's developer was kind enough to give me a custom script. The theme has a section in the dashboard where you can input custom JavaScript or CSS that made the slider (that was originally in the mid-section or body of the webpage) become the website's Hero Slider.
3. The said built-in slider, however, is very limited. The placement of the buttons, the transitions, and other functionalities are very limited.

Here's where I need assistance.

So I downloaded a slider plugin that pretty much allowed me to create my desired slider. How do I go about using the same method the developer did to move the said slider from the mid-section of my web page to the header?

**Here's his code**

```
$(function(){
    if($('.ptsc.set-as-header').length > 0)
    {
        $('.main-content>.title-group').after($('.ptsc.set-as-header'));
        $('.main-content>.title-group').remove();
    }
});
```

- Incidentally, he asked me to set the slider's css class to `set-as-header`
- Let's say my new slider's css class is `set-as-header-again`

Comment: Which slider plugin are you using?

Comment: @KashifRafique I am using SmartSlider 3 as my plugin.

Comment: [Smart Slider 3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-slider-3/) can be added to your page using shortcode `[smartslider3 slider=Here comes the slider id]`. I am not sure how your theme is generating this page. Most theme use WordPress default content area with their own shortcodes. If your theme is also following this, then you can locate the slider section and replace the current slider content with Smart Slider 3 shortcode.